# PySpark Executors not running task

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute some job which runs as follows:

1. Reads a parquet file from s3 bucket
2. Does some filtering
3. Use a udf for processing a column (processing is a little heavy as it uses some ml libraries)
4. Save back as parquet to s3

Execution Plan Seems to be like this:

```
= Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [field_id#0, field_id#1, field_id#2, pythonUDF0#12 AS field_id#0#7]
+- BatchEvalPython [<lambda>(field_id#2)], [field_id#0, field_id#1, field_id#2, pythonUDF0#12]
   +- *(1) Filter ((length(field_id#2) > 0) && (length(field_id#2) < 5000))
      +- *(1) FileScan parquet [field_id#0, field_id#1, field_id#2] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3 bucket, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<field1:string,field2:string,field3:string
```

Size of data is around 5GB, partitions 260 and config for workers and drivers:

```
 --worker-count 30 \
    --worker-cores 1 \
    --worker-memory 8G \
    --driver-memory 64G \
    --driver-cores 6
```

Spark UI. [[image: enter image description here1]
[image]

I am trying to understand what does Input Size/Records mean? It seems to be increasing really slowly, Is it not able to download data rapidly from the s3 bucket? or the udf function I am using is slow? And also from the second picture, it seems Duration of task is 0ms, if it's running then why duration is not increasing?

```
@f.udf(returnType=StringType())
def preprocess_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = remove_stopwords(text) // Nlp library function 
    text = lemmatize_text(text) // NLP Library function
    return text

df = df.withColumn("processed_text",preprocess_text(f.col(text))
```

Comment: Why is it that your driver uses so much memory?
Can you share your UDF? 
UDF is an expensive operation and it depends what is the logic inside.
for example, crossJoin can lead even this size of that to running tasks forever.

another option is the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` maybe you should increase / decrease it
But it depends. do you see shuffling ? 

share more info.

Comment: I don't think it's using all this memory, I just allocated it for debugging if that was the issue. I have share the logic inside udf, it uses nlp library for stopwords and lemmatization, there is no shuffle and cross join. It's just simple udf; though I think this preprocessing is inefficient.